# Warning: rename(try,../def.ini): in C:\xampp\htdocs\up\admin\definitions.php on line 29

Tags: php, file

I have this code:

```
if (!rename("try", $this->filename)) return false;
```

I try to change the name of `try` to the name in the variable
And I get the next error:

> Warning: rename(try,../def.ini): in C:\xampp\htdocs\up\admin\definitions.php on line 29

I dont know what this error men since nothing write in there only warning

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @haytem its not as variable name, its just string, but never mind I find the solution I will write it soon

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the file `try` was open before by `fopen` function
So I did before the `rename` function:

```
 fclose($file);
```

And now its work.